# Адреса при хранении в базе данных

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть база данных с адресами. Думаю над структурой. На данный момент есть таблицы: Типы улиц, Улицы, Типы населенных пунктов, Населенные пункты. Вопрос вот в чем. Проспект Ленина в Красноярске и Проспект Ленина в Томске - это же разные сущности, значит в таблице Улицы должны быть такие строки?

ИД/Населенный пункт/Тип улицы/Имя

1/1/1/Ленина

2/2/1/Ленина

Или в таблице Улицы не нужен столбец Населенный пункт, а вместо этого сделать отдельную таблицу для связи [Улица-Населенный пункт] и Проспект Ленина не будет дублироваться для каждого города?

Comment: нафига разные? "Зеленое" в Новосибирске и в Свердловске разные сущности? Сущность одна, название. А в таблице по адресу идет ссылка на наименование улицы. Томск/34 - где 34 ссылка на уникальный id с наименованием улицы

Comment: Всегда старайтесь что бы БД отражали сущности реального мира. Физически улицы в разных городах разные - значит и в БД должны быть разными. А название - это не сущность, это обычный атрибут. Захотите вы завтра добавить в БД дома или географические координаты точек на улицах. К чему вы их привяжете, если сущностями будут названия. И интересно ради чего вы вводите "типы улиц". У вас в БД что то зависит от типа, т.е. например что то работает только с проспектами ? Конечно можно для них хранить полное/сокращенное название "Улица-ул", ну собственно и все.

Answer (score 6):

Это абсолютно разные сущности, и вот почему - захотят в Усть-Тарапыгинске переименовать "улицу Ленина" в "Гнилой тупик", и вы получите кучу веселых проблем с выделением этой улицы из всех остальных городов.

Причем, вам нужно будет, по хорошему, учитывать, "историчность", потому как часть данных будет относится к старому названию, а часть - к новому.

Скопируйте в базу структуру КЛАДР или ФАИС, вам же проще будет.

Comment: Да, я об этом думал. Однако, в итоге с переименованием проблем не увидел. Переименование будет означать изменение в таблице "ГородУлица" идентификатора улицы с одного на другой (который соответствует новому имени и типу и будет добавлен, если такой улицы еще нет в справочнике). Про историчность даже не думал, но навскидку могу предложить еще одно развитие событий. Решат те же ребята, о которых вы сказали, переименовать улицу Ленина в Гнилой тупик, а потом спохватятся, как же про Ленина то забыли и переименуют проспект Пупкина в Улицу Ленина. Чем в этом случае поможет историчность?

Comment: @iRumba в любом случае, улицы Ленина в разных городах никак не эквивалентны в реальности, кроме сиюминутного совпадения названий. Поэтому нет смысла создавать лишнюю сущность в виде связки многих городов с одной улицей.

Comment: тут встает вопрос о целостности данных. А что, если в качестве адреса я захочу выбрать только город без улицы? Значит, в таблице с адресами нужна ссылка не только на улицу, но и на город. Но тогда (чисто теоретически) будет возможность добавить в таблицу идентификатор города и идентификатор улицы, которая находится в другом городе.